# Rename ASP.Net Identity 2.0 Tables: Context has changed since the database was created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, ef-database-first

I already have my database and I need to use ASP.Net Identity 2.0. So I did the following:

Get the SQL Script of identity tables:

- Create an MVC Project with Authentication Individual User Account
- Then, script the database that get created under Default Connection

Then, I intergrated it with my existing DB:

- Insert the scripted tables into existing database in SQL Server
  Management Studio.

After I generated My Identity Database, i started added the necessary columns to the table "ASPNetUsers" by using EF Migrations for DB First.

- I created a new MVC Project using Database First Approach
- Now, i have 2 connection strings in web.config

As a result, I have the Asp.Identity Tables in my db with ER model in my application.

Then, I started adding new properties:

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

After adding each property, i executed the Migrations commands: Add-Migration and Update-Database.

Then, i tried to register new user with the added columns populated all is working fine.

However, I need to change the name of the Table, so I used Fluent API:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Account");

    }
```

when running the app and trying to create a new user it gives me the following error:

[image]

Comment: Have you run a Add-Migration and Update-Database after adding the fluent renaming?

Comment: I am not sure this is correct way to resolve this issue. So try it once after taking a backup of db . Find the table named like _migrationhistory or something like that and delete its contents.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not updated your model yet.
If you are using Code First please follow the instructions given on

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

basically execute these commands in the package manager console:

1. enable-migrations
2. add-migration InitialCreate
3. update-database

If you need to do changes after first migration you should execute:

1. add-migration
2. update-database